# how to pass a layer into two layers in parallel at the same time in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have implemented a neural network in Keras, but for some reasons, I need to implement the network in TensorFlow. My problem is that I need to pass `h1` into two layers in parallel. I have searched a lot to pass a layer into two layers at the same time but I cannot find the correct way. The Keras code is as below:

```
  x = keras.layers.Input(shape=(input_dim))
  hp_units1 = hp.Int('units', min_value=1, max_value=15, step=1)
  h1 = keras.layers.Dense(hp_units1, activation = 'sigmoid', name='dense_1')(x)
  t = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='time_prediction')(h1)
  decoded = keras.layers.Dense(input_dim, activation='linear', name='decoded_mean')(h1)
```

Thus, I need to pass `h1` to `t` and `decoded` at the same time.

Comment: Are you working with tf1 and keras? or tf2? because in tf2 you can just use the exact same code as keras.

Comment: I work with tf2. Can you please explain more how can I use the same keras code in tf2? Thanks.

Comment: do check the answer to see how you can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import `keras` from tensorflow 2. The same syntax is available in tensorflow 2 -

```
from tensorflow import keras

x = keras.layers.Input(shape=(input_dim))
hp_units1 = hp.Int('units', min_value=1, max_value=15, step=1)
h1 = keras.layers.Dense(hp_units1, activation = 'sigmoid', name='dense_1')(x)
t = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='time_prediction')(h1)
decoded = keras.layers.Dense(input_dim, activation='linear', name='decoded_mean')(h1)
```